# How to enable SMTP on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: smtp, email-server, windows-server-2016, mx-record, dns-zone

I recently purchased VPS service to allow me to host a site. My mail provider is zoho.com. In order to get it to work, I would need to add 3 entries under Mail Exchange records (MX Record) as the following page instruct https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/configure-email-delivery.html

I enabled SMTP service following the instruction listed here https://www.znetlive.com/blog/how-to-configure-smtp-server-in-windows-server-2016/

Then I opened port 25.

Then I went under "DNS Manager" and added the following info

[image]

But still can't get it to work. Zoho mail can't see the MX records. I tried to check the status of the mail setup https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/realestatebyareen.com/

But that is given me errors.

How can I fix this issue and correctly setup SMTP and add the MX records?

**UPDATED**
Here is a screenshot of my updated DNS Manager records
[image]

Comment: You need to change the DNS records for _your own domain name_. This has nothing to do with your Windows server.

Comment: My domain name has DNS (name servers) pointing to the VPS which is why it renders www.realestatebyareen.com. Not sure what I am missing here

Comment: You don't have a forward lookup zone for that domain, though!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am kinda confused. I think I added it now. Can you please check the updated images in my question?

Comment: That's your domain name, but these records have no effect, because your DNS is not hosted on your VPS. Contact your hosting provider for further information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for your help. I am not sure what to ask for. the name server used with the domain is `CDNS1.INTERSERVER.NET`, `CDNS2.INTERSERVER.NET` Is that what need to be added under "ForwardLookup Zones"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88266/discussion-between-mike-a-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 0):

Only the following MX record exists for your domain realestatebyarean.com.

```
dig -t MX realestatebyareen.com +short
25 mail.realestatebyareen.com.
```

It is highly unlikely that your VPS windows machine is the authoritative DNS server for realestatebyarean.com, as you generally need at least two authoritative DNS servers for a domain.

The authoritative DNS servers for your domain is currently:

```
dig -t NS realestatebyareen.com +short
cdns2.interserver.net.
cdns3.interserver.net.
cdns1.interserver.net.
```

You would need to add the MX records that you want (and you would only need one that points to the domain name of your VPS host) in the zone file of the authoritative name server for your domain.